# Google Drive API - get Public Files

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to get files marked for public viewing in Google Drive using the API without authentication?

I know about the "downloadUrl" property, but it is a temporary URL with no reference to how long it lasts. I would like to use the API directly to get the files, and I think I read somewhere someone alluding to the possibility of calls to the API that are not authenticated for retrieving public files.

Comment: This has been asked before. Try this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116152/how-do-i-get-a-file-list-for-a-google-drive-public-hosted-folder/38298877#38298877

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The `webContentLink` field of a File resource now provides this.

This is a known issue, and a big deal which we are working to fix. Currently, some sort of authentication is required, even for public files, which I think is not ideal. Sorry about that.

Comment: Any progress on this Ali? webContentLink does give me an URL, but only works if I am signed in, even if the file is shared to "Public"

Comment: That should not be the case, public files should not require cookie auth. Can you confirm this please.

Comment: You mentioned yourself that this was a known issue that was being worked on. Here is a the 'webContentLink' to a file with sharing set to "public." https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B6Cpn8NXwgGPcmJZYThTUGg5RGM&export=download | it always requires me to log in to see it.

Comment: I see your edit that this is now webContentLink instead of downloadUrl, which I had discovered to be added recently. however, it still requires login for public files as shown in the above comment. Thanks! this is the last feature I need to complete my app! thanks Google for Drive. I've been waiting some time for a product like this.

Comment: Is webContentLink a temporary URL like downloadUrl?

Comment: @AliAfshar .... if we are not able to get public url..then how Google Drive App for iOS is streaming video ..plz u must reply...

Comment: @AliAfshar.. Did you find solution for this ? I want to get all files from public url of a directory ? Is it possible ?