# How do I get a file list for a Google Drive public hosted folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to get a file listing **without using authorization** for a publicly hosted Goolge Drive folder?

Example folder: https://googledrive.com/host/0B1Nmfb7VDM6jNnhjWk9CdU9ueHc/

I want to use the folder to host images that I will display in a gallery on other sites.

Comment: I am closing this question because Google has discontinued drive hosting.
http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Comment: but its still relevant now, even without the hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it unauthenticated. However, you can authenticate as ANY user and get the list with [drive.children.list()](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.children.list?folderId=0B1Nmfb7VDM6jNnhjWk9CdU9ueHc&_h=2&)

Comment: How would you create the service instance on a server?

Comment: That's not the case. Maybe it was at the time this was posted but you can get the content of a public folder without having to authenticate. You will still need an API key. See my answer below please.

Answer (score 26):

OK there is a way and it's pretty simple, it just needs a bit of setup. We need to get a Google Drive URL that can return JSONP, then run the request against it.

### The setup

Generate the public URL. Go to:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_GB#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list

In the 'q' field enter the following:

```
'{your_public_folder_id}' in parents
```

Click the "Execute without OAuth" link underneath the button.

You should now see all your files listed underneath. It also show you the **GET request**. **That is the URL you will need.**

Copy the Request URL. Something like: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='{your_public_folder_id}'+in+parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Now, you will need to generate the API key.
Go to Google Console: https://console.developers.google.com/
In left menu select 'Credentials'.
Click 'Create credentials' and select API key.
Click 'Browser key'
Copy the generate key.

### The execution

You can now do something like this:

```
var api_key = '{YOUR_API_KEY}';
var folderId = '{your_public_folder_id}';
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + folderId + "'+in+parents&key=" + api_key;
var promise = $.getJSON( url, function( data, status){
    // on success
});
promise.done(function( data ){
    // do something with the data
}).fail(function(){

});
```

Comment: awesome!! super cool!! The only way/workaround to get the children of a folder without authentication I guess!! Kudos @iDevGeek :)

Comment: THis is great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! And BTW for anyone else out there: once you have the API key, you can get a direct download link to any sized file in google drive with this link: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### fileId ###?alt=media&key=### API key ###    

see more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588701/node-js-provide-direct-link-for-google-drive-file/54642410#54642410

Comment: could share a full link without your key? or example using api exploerer

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to list a public folder - just use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fgoogledrive.com%2Fhost%2F0B1Nmfb7VDM6jNnhjWk9CdU9ueHc%2F%22%20and%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%5C'folder-cell%5C'%5D%2Fa%22) to get XML or JSON results.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative solution --without using any API keys-- is to use google app-script to generate a text file for the directory, and put that script on a trigger every day or so to refresh it if the directory changes, then simply make that google doc file, that is modified by the google apps script, with the public URL plus `/export?format=txt` at the end, or for a regular file, something like `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=INSERT_ID_HERE`, and that is then publicly accessible on the web with no authorization

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have a problem with this request, just use this template: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27{YOUR FOLDER ID}%27+in+parents&key={YOUR API KEY}` without the brackets.
It really helps me, because these "'" characters problem is the drag

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do in PHP

- Create a Project in your Google Cloud Console
- Get a service account JSON file by going into Navigation Menu > IAM & Admin > Service Accounts
- Run the following code to list all files in your requested Folder ID

```
    <?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
        throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
    }

    $client = new Google_Client();
    // set the location manually
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setApplicationName("My Application");
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    // Print the names and IDs for up to 100 files.
    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 100,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
        'q' => "'YOUR_FOLDER_ID' in parents",
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

    if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
        print "No files found.\n";
    } else {
        print "Files:\n";
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your expanded google drive url  is [this](https://d95b2b8c54c1827d7a316594f5436a81b5bb2b76.googledrive.com/host/0B1Nmfb7VDM6jNnhjWk9CdU9ueHc/) ,so use the expanded url as following to get all files ending in ".html" extension.  This example uses ajax call using jquery.

Tweak the script according to your need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dir = "https://d95b2b8c54c1827d7a316594f5436a81b5bb2b76.googledrive.com/host/0B1Nmfb7VDM6jNnhjWk9CdU9ueHc/";
var fileextension = ".html";
$.ajax({
//This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
url: dir,
success: function (data) {
    //Lsit all png file names in the page
    $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
        var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "");
        console.log(filename);
        filename = filename.split("/").pop();
        $("body").append($("<a href=" + dir + filename + ">" + filename + "</a>"));
    });
    });
}
});
</script>
```

This will log all finename(.html) to console and add hyperlink for each filename to end of body.